# scala-library.jar vanished from pom.xml

Tags: scala, sbt

I had tried to compile an sbt managed project against Scala 2.10.2-RC2 and 2.10.3-RC1 (the latter isn't published yet, so that didn't go through), only to revert again to `scalaVersion := "2.10.0"`.

Now I have the problem that **the published `pom.xml` does not contain any more the entry for `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library"`**. It simply vanished.

I am using `retrieveManaged := true`. All libraries are indeed there, and `sbt gen-idea` does pull the sources and docs for `scala-library.jar`.

I tried `sbt reboot`, `sbt clean update` etc., no luck.

sbt version is 0.12.3. I need the magic reset command to bring this bastard back to reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was introduced by me already earlier on, using

```
libraryDependencies <<= version { v => ... }
```

instead of

```
libraryDependencies <++= version { v => ... }
```

So that somehow overwrote the initial settings which has scala-library included.